# Edit и memo / ограничения / Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

**Интересует ответ на такой вопрос:** Как в **edit и в memo** поставить ограничение на **минимальное** количество - введенных символов. То есть, если символов введено в edit и memo **меньше** двух то тогда кнопка Button1 **неактивна**, если введено два символа и больше то тогда кнопка Button1 активна.

Answer (score 1):

В этом вопросе тоже задачу решила.

```
Button1.Enabled :=Length(Edit1.Text)>=2
```